# Selenium + FirefoxDriver access global javascript object

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I want to check the value of a global object using Selenium. But so far I couldn't do it using FirefoxDriver...

Running something like `driver.ExecuteScript("return 1+2");` does return 3 as expected; running `driver.ExecuteScript("return myObject");` does work with the Chrome driver but yields null in FirefoxDriver.

The following works in Chrome, but throws an exception in Firefox:

```
 //driver is either an instance of FirefoxDriver or ChromeDriver
 driver.Url = "https://www.google.com";
 driver.Navigate();
 //gbar is a global object at google.com
 var result = driver.ExecuteScript("return gbar");
 Assert.NotNull(result);
```

The exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : ReferenceError: gbar is not defined (UnexpectedJavaScriptError)
StackTrace: 
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ExecuteScriptCommand(String script, String commandName, Object[] args)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ExecuteScript(String script, Object[] args)
   at ...
```

Using Selenium.Webdriver 2.53.0 and Firefox developer edition 48.0a2, and regular Firefox 46.0.1 running on Win10, .Net 4.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `gbar` is not yet defined at the time you are calling `ExecuteScript`. I would try to wait for it:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
var result = wait.Until((drv) => drv.ExecuteScript("return window.gbar || null;"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea (at least now I know this Selenium feature), but no luck. When I was exploring selenium, the browser spent minutes at the google homepage with debugger attached. Also tried to access the object thru the window, but no luck with that either...

Comment: It could be due to your version of Firefox. Your example works fine with me on Win8.1/Firefox 46. Can you at least get the variable in the console of the browser launched with Selenium?

Comment: Well, just checked regular Firefox v.46.0.1, and same result. The variable is present in the opened FF's console, but can't get it with Selenium. For example sending an alert('hi') shows the alert box in the browser too.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue on FirefoxDriver when try to run JQuery code.

Error:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined (UnexpectedJavaScriptError) firefox
>   selenium

Run fine on ChromeDriver with the same code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to inject custom functions to a running web page for testing. The functions were visible in chrome driver but not with firefox.

The solution was to inject these functions into window scope. Then you can reference them without the "window" prefix. The following will work:

```
driver.executeScript("window.mystuff = 'somestuff'")
driver.executeScript("return mystuff")
```